# Differents between private cache and public cache in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Im trying to use cache with symfony.

in my controller I write this snippet

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
    ]);

    $response->setMaxAge(10);
    $response->setPublic();
    return $response;
}
```

and in my twig I have a function `random(100)` then I enabled also `$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);` in app_dev.php and app.php
When refresh I see the same "random number" for 10 second, and it's ok.

If I Omit `$response->setPublic();`, the cache becomes private, and I have always the different numbers. I tried also to login to my application, but the cache seems don't work

I tried also to add getOptions in appCache()

```
class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'debug'                  => false,
            'default_ttl'            => 0,
            'private_headers'        => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
            'allow_reload'           => false,
            'allow_revalidate'       => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
            'stale_if_error'         => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what's your question, can you be more clear about it?

Comment: Sure! when I use $response->setPublic(); the cache works, (to test I use random(100) in twig and i see the same number for 10 sec), if I Use $response->setPrivate() I have always the different number (when refresh the browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cache is *private*, you tell to the reverse proxy that you **don't want** cache the response. Symfony will send this header:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

and this bypass the intermediate proxy, since the response is intended for a *single user*. In this case you work with the browser cache. If you want do otherwise, set it as `public`.

You can read more about it here: [public vs private response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#public-vs-private-responses).

Comment: When I use private, I don't use cache ?
I understand that cache private is for single user (like logged used).

Comment: No, if you set `Cache-Control: private` you just don't use the cache of the reverse proxy, but you still can use the browser's cache

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the answer that I'm looking for !